# How can I get the certificate into specific store/container automatically?

Tags: certificate, store

We have Windows Server 2012 R2 with installed Certification Authority role.
There we have certificate templates.
I want to get certificate from this server of specific template into specific container automatically by autoenrollment.
Now I automatically get certificate into **personal** store by group policy and autoenrollment. 
But I want to get certificate into the **specific** store (for example, custom SCCM or SMS) **automatically by autoenrollment**.